# DIV.disabled cannot use for Firefox browser [vb]

Tags: html, forms

I have a problem with that I don't know how can I control Mozilla Firefox in VB program. Because the program works in IE8, but I cannot use the 'DIV.disabled' with Firefox.

(I use Visual Studio 2010)
If anyone has the same problem or knows how to fix, please reply it.

Comment: `DIV` Tag not have `disabled` attribute.

Comment: So, was the answer helpfull? Did you manage to solve this issue? Please update this SO item...

Answer (score 0):

The 'disabled' attribute is not part of the [global attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp). You may only use it on form fields like `<input>` and `<select>`.

Either use a form field or, alternatively, use a class name and let CSS and Javascript handle the 'disabled-ness'...